# How do I open a .dat from a FUJIFILM FinePix AV100?

Tags: fujifilm

I am not sure if I am in the right place so apologies if I am not. A client has sent me two images taken with a FUJIFILM FinePix AV100. They are in a .dat format which I am not sure is even an image. Is there any way to open these, or has my client sent me the wrong files entirely?

I opened the files in Notepad, which is how I found the reference to a FUJIFILM FinePix AV100.

Thank's in advance

Comment: It sounds like what you have are actually sidecar files, containing only metadata about the corresponding images. I'm not familiar with that model of camera, but to tell for sure, how big are the file sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually turned out that the .DAT was actually a .JPEG, with the extension changed for some reason. Whatever software came with the camera probably just renamed the extension while importing from the camera, and the client copied it direct via USB.

Thanks for the suggestions anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It is most probable that what you have received is not an image and it is just some metadata from the camera (or EXIF data) in .DAT format. So, you could ask your client to recheck his mail attachments.

Or, before doing that, there's one more thing you could do.

Sometimes video files are also stored as .DAT, and unless you are 100% sure that it could NOT be a video file you may use any of the software on this [link](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fileextensions/tp/free-video-converter.htm) to convert your file into some 'playable' format to check if it's a video or not.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer but it actually turned out that the .dat was really a .jpg, with the extension changed for some odd reason. I'd upvote you if I had the rep on this Stack.